# Sublime Text identation on square brackets (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, sublimetext3

so I use Sublime text 3 to code JS and I noticed a small but very annoying bug(?).

I have this code

```
var x = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
]
```

And Sublime auto indents to:

```
var x = [
"a",
"b",
"c"
]
```

This is bugging me alot (no pun  intended) because I have big array declarations and nested arrays and I can't fold them or have a clear look at the hierarchy.

So I went and snooped around on sublime syntax dictionaries. (converted the hexas to ASCII chars) and found this:

[image: code]

I guess that modifying the regex we can change the indentation rule. But I suck at regex expressions, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have seen, the [JavaScript indentation rules](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/61bfd68ea07a3aede68cd6a65c80be702b3d6db8/JavaScript/JavaScript%20Indent.tmPreferences) can be found using https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer.

Currently, the rules indent on `{` if not followed by a string or a closing `}`, and they unindent on `}` at the beginning of the line (optionally preceded by a closing block comment). You can change them to also indent on `[` if not followed by a closing square bracket, and unindent on `}` or `]` - here are some regex patterns equally as crude albeit functional as the original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>JavaScript Indent</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.js</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>decreaseIndentPattern</key>
        <string>^(.*\*/)?\s*[}\]].*$</string>
        <key>increaseIndentPattern</key>
        <string>^.*[{\[][^}"'\]]*$</string>

        <key>bracketIndentNextLinePattern</key>
        <string>(?x)
        ^ \s* \b(if|while|else)\b [^;]* $
        | ^ \s* \b(for)\b .* $
        </string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Solved it :D